# Is it possible to disable font fallbacks in CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I need to render text in exactly one font, without system fallbacks. Is it possible to disable the automatic fallback to system fonts?

Ideally, if the font doesn't have a character that is typed, I'd like to be able to know that so that I can tell the user to use a different font. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Set `font-family: "Your font name";`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. https://jsfiddle.net/brandoncc/6rf71sm9/ On my system, Google Chrome renders the text with the font "PingFang SC" even though I have set the font to "Arial". I'm certain something similar will happen on your system (although your system might be a different fallback font). This is the exact situation I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: To be clear, I do set the font family that I need to render in, I'm just trying to disable the fallback. Thanks for the attempt, though!

Comment: You have to make sure that the font you set is available in the browser. Otherwise it doesn't make sense at all =))

Comment: I have a problem I am trying to solve. If I could achieve what I asked, it would be one possible solution. I do realize you don't know what the problem I'm solving is, but "making sense" is definitely subjective. It absolutely _does_ make sense for my use case. If the user needs to change the selected font, I would like to be able to tell them (or maybe even change it automatically). The user input is re-rendered in non-browser environments, which is why I HAVE to know what the correct font is. I can't rely on the fallback fonts, so I would like to turn them off. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the lecture, sir. I wanted to say that if the font used in `font-family` was not loaded in the browser, browser uses the fallback. So it doesn't make sense to set `Arial` if it's not available. If you have to check if the font is available, you might use JS to check whether it falls back and do something accordingly. Actually it would be great if you elaborated a bit on what you're trying to do, what your expected and actual results are. So I would not do these stupid assumptions. Cheers.

Comment: I wasn't trying to lecture you, sorry about that. I was pretty clear on my requirements, but you told me they don't make any sense. :-) I just found that Adobe Typekit had exactly the same need as I have and they solved it using a font style like this: "font-family: Arial, adobe-notdef". "adobe-notdef" seems to render every character as a box with an "X" in it. This is another good solution to my problem....so I am going to investigate it more and try to replicate. Thanks again for your time and your help!

Comment: If anyone else finds themselves needing to solve this problem, the adobe-notdef font license (as of Feb 20, 2022) allows anyone to use it and is available here: https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-notdef